# Javascript if else compiler bug?

Tags: javascript, v8, spidermonkey

Could this be a javascript compiler error with else if.

Here is the code;

```
"use strict"
var me ;
var a=1;
if (a==1)
{me ="hello"}
else if (a==2)
{me ="bye"}
else id (a==3) 
{me ="ups"}
console.log(me)
```

Note that I have '**id**' and not '**if**' .

You have a final 'ups' value for 'me' ....
And no error....

Checked with chrome & firefox

What is happen ?

Comment: `id (…)` is a function call. It's the only content of the `else` block. Following that is another block with superfluous `{}` which will always be executed.

Comment: And because the `else` block is never reached, you're not getting a *"id is not defined"* error either.

Comment: @adeneo . De 'd' letter is very near 'f' letter. IMHO the compiler would have to rise an error.....I have not id function....

Comment: There's no error if the undefined function call never happens.

Comment: It is not just a typo ? id => if ?

Comment: @aprovent Yeeeees…?! And the question is why this code behaves the way it does *with this typo*.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
…
else {
  id(a == 3);
}

{
  me = "ups";
}
```

Yes, you can have `{}` brackets to enclose code blocks even without any `if` statement or such, it simply won't do anything special in this case. The `me = "ups"` statement will always be executed because it's not associated with the `else` clause, the `id()` function call is the only statement associated with that block.

No, it's not a compiler bug, it's what you wrote.